# Hibernate issue while Migrating JBOSS EAP 7.1.5 to JBOSS EAP 7.2

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

Currently we are using "hibernate-core-5.1.10.Final-redhat-1.jar" with JBoss 7.1.6.

When we see the server log, we have to do lot of change in our code as it clearly indicates that query parameters longer supported and you should use the JPA-style ordinal parameters.

This is because our new JBoss 7.2.5 is with "hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar", and it is observed that multiple things got deprecated from hibernate-core-5.3.7.

1. Can we use same "hibernate-core-5.1.10.Final-redhat-1.jar" with new JBoss 7.2.5?
2. If Yes, then how we can achieve this?
3. If No, what needs to done to resolve this hibernate issues?

Thanks,

Apekshit